# "Search for unknown operator" On Start-Up After Removing Module and Shortcuts

Tags: python, shortcut, operator

For lack of a less drastic alternative, I created a whole module just for setting `bpy.context.window.screen` to a specific screen, since `bpy.ops.screen.screen_set` is relative.

I originally named the module's operator class `SCREEN_OT_set_screen` and operator `screen.set_screen`, played with setting the shortcuts both in the user preferences menu and in code, then changed the name to `SCREEN_OT_set` and the operator `screen.set`.

Despite wiping any references to it in User Preferences->Input and double-checking by looping through all items of all keymaps of all keyconfigs, I still get this twice on Blender startup:

> search for unknown operator 'SCREEN_OT_set_screen',
>   'SCREEN_OT_set_screen'
> search for unknown operator
>   'SCREEN_OT_set_screen', 'SCREEN_OT_set_screen'

I make sure to set the shortcut key after registering the operator class, and it persists when I rename the module class back to the `SCREEN_OT_set_screen` that it's looking for, or even remove the file from `scripts/addons` entirely.

Where in Blender's start-up process is it likely still looking for this and failing?

Answer (score 0):

Search for "SCREEN_OT_set_screen" (literally, a text search) in your startup files. On Windows they're located in **C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\config\**.
The files are "userpref.blend" and "startup.blend", you can open them with a text editor.

First, backup these files to somewhere safe.

Delete all the text starting from and including the first "DATA" word right *before* the first occurrence of your operator name, until the next "DATA" word after the last occurrence, but don't delete this last "DATA" word as it's the start of a neighbor entry.
Then save and try opening Blender. Save your user preferences and startup file from within Blender, just to make sure.